# Read from file into config

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an ember project. The root folder has a file called version which just says 1.1.0

In the root folder I also have my client folder (ember project) with a config folder and then environment.js for my app variables.

Im trying to read from the version file and add its contents in the environment.js file as a varaible.

Im currently trying like this: version: $.getJSON("../../VERSION")

but im getting the unexpected identifier error. With Node I would use: version: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../VERSION').toString().trim(),

How would I do this with ember? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the version in environment.js and expose it as an ENV key-value pair in the ENV hash/object.

environment.js is the only[1] file with access to things outside of the frontend / browser environment.

Once you have your ENV saying what version you have (maybe via `fs`), you can then import the enviroment via `import ENV from 'app-name/config/environment'`, and access your version via `ENV.versionPropertyThingThatYouMade`

hope this helps!

[1] there are others, but that's not important right now